# Is there no built-in function for the girth of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The girth of a graph is the length of one of its (if any) shortest graph cycles.

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/Girth.html

I noticed that Mathematica seems to only have the Girth function in the *Combinatorica* package. It's strange that Mathematica doesn't have it built-in, since it's a very basic function. Did I miss something? Are there any alternative functions available in Mathematica?

---

**To calculate the girth of a graph, do we need to compute the lengths of all cycles and then compare them?**

By [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(graph_theory)), the girth of an undirected graph can be computed by running a breadth-first search from each node, with complexity $O(nm)$ where $n$ is the number of vertices of the graph and $m$ is the number of edges.

Comment: IGraph/M has `IGGirth`. With built-ins, you could try to implementing something in terms of `FindCycle` (look for larger and larger cycles until there's a match). Or you can do it in terms of `BreadthFirstScan`, as you described, but that is a bit more trouble.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. From a practical perspective, `IGGirth` in IGraph/M  is the best for calculating the girth of a graph. Below are implementations in other languages using depth-first search algorithm to compute the girth. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-cycle-in-an-undirected-unweighted-graph/